# How to define a global variable with Mason

Tags: perl, cgi, mason

### Intro

- I tried to set up mason in my Ubuntu desktop.
- It is a very simple set up, but I still had problems, after reading
  parts of masonbook.com & mansonhq.com
- I hope someone can give me a hint. Please see below for more detail.

### Local server

- Ubuntu 11.04 desktop
- Mason 1.44 (coming with Ubuntu)

  Newbie to perl/mason

### Files

- mason.seedy2 - It is a cgi script. Basically, I set up a global variable --> $user. I want to use it in index1.html
- index1.html - simple html file
- apache.conf - I am not sure I did it correctly

### Error

```
1. type http://localhost:81/index1.html in browser

2.

error:      Error during compilation of /var/www/test/sj3/public_html/index1.html:
Global symbol "$user" requires explicit package name at /var/www/test/sj3/public_html/index1.html line 2.

context:    
1:      
2:      
3:      
4:      
code stack:     /usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/Interp.pm:450
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/Request.pm:249
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/Request.pm:212
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/ApacheHandler.pm:94
/usr/share/perl5/Class/Container.pm:275
/usr/share/perl5/Class/Container.pm:353
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/Interp.pm:348
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/ApacheHandler.pm:874
/usr/share/perl5/HTML/Mason/ApacheHandler.pm:828
(eval 34):8
-e:0
```

### apache.conf

```
# Listen to other ports
Listen 81



    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/sj3/public_html                                             

    PerlSetVar  MasonCompRoot    /var/www/test/sj3/public_html/
    PerlSetVar  MasonDataDir     /var/www/test/sj3/mason/

    Action html-mason /cgi-bin/mason.speedy2
     
            SetHandler   perl-script
            PerlHandler  HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler
```

### index1.html

```
print %user
```

### mason.speedy2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use HTML::Mason::CGIHandler;

{
    our($user, %session);
    $user = "bla";
}

my $h = HTML::Mason::CGIHandler->new
(
    data_dir  => "$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../mason",
    allow_globals => [qw(%session $user)],
);

$h->handle_request;
```

Comment: @mob: that's an answer, not a comment

Comment: Not a good answer, though -- the error message is about `$user` being undeclared. There's probably a typo or two in this post.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have [site wide globals](http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Admin.html#global_variables), you declare them with [allow_globals](http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Params.html#allow_globals) in the apache handler, and initialize them in the root level [autohandler](http://www.masonbook.com/book/chapter-3.mhtml#TOC-ANCHOR-4).

Answer (score 0):

1. print %user is a typo. It should be $user.
2. daotoad's suggestion is good, but it will take me a while to change the existing codes
3. The previous programmer has "/cgi-bin/mason.speedy2" containing all the global variables and package, then embedding /cgi-bin/mason.speedy2 in apache.conf (i.e. is similar to declare them in autohandler). 4. My question: Is /cgi-bin/mason.speedy2 running? If it is running, why the global variable $user is not defined?